# Можно ли избежать глобальных переменных?

Tags: c++, xml, sax

Использую библиотеку libxml в общем и sax парсер в частности. Интерфейс этой библиотеки предполагает callback реализацию. Причём все функции этого интерфейса возвращают void, а также не предполагают передачу иных параметров в себя кроме тех что есть в описании. К примеру:

```
void startElement(  void *  user_data,
    const xmlChar *     name,
    const xmlChar **    attrs);
```

А мне необходимо накопление информации об объектах из xml файла. Есть ли способ сделать это не используя глобальные переменные? Почему спрашиваю - есть утверждение, что использование глобальных переменных это не лучшее правило в программировании. Использую SAX, а не SAX2 т.к. возможно использование только старой версии.

Comment: Дак тут либо локальные, либо глобальные переменные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void * user_data
```

Очень похоже, что это место для указателя на вашу структуру или объект, содержащий все необходимые переменные как поля, как раз, чтобы не делать глобальными.